# flutter - fab button animation which will go to top from bottom

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation

I need help with the animation, when I click on the FAB icon in the first screen the icon will go up with animation and  the other screen (shown in second image) should be displayed with animation like curtain. And the fab icon should be set in the app bar just like second image.

Bottom menu should be there in both of the screen just like the screenshots given.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you can do one thing that just wrap floating action button to AnimatedContainer

```
   AlignmentDirectional _ironManAlignment = AlignmentDirectional.bottomCenter; 

   ...

   floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.centerDocked,
   floatingActionButton: AnimatedContainer(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2),
        alignment: _ironManAlignment,
        child: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {
            _flyIronMan();
          },
          child: Icon(Icons.add),
        ),
      ),
```

like this
when you press button then call this method

```
  void _flyIronMan() {
    setState(() {
      _ironManAlignment =
          AlignmentDirectional(0.0, -0.8); //AlignmentDirectional(0.0,-0.7);
    });
  }
```

Comment: thank you for your reply but I also want to open new page with animation and remove fab icon from bottom and set to second page app bar. So could you please give me some example for that so I can implement it in real quick? It would be a great help to me.

Comment: I think you don't need second page . You can use bottom sheet widget

Comment: But how can I use it to make my desire screen which I have shown in design? Actually I am new to flutter and I don't know much more about this widget. Could you please guide me to do this?

Comment: Yes sure why not

Comment: “Flutter 5 — Bottom Sheet” by Ishan Fernando https://link.medium.com/C3HkSWmI15. Please refer it

Comment: But there should be bottom menu in another screen then how will be possible it in bottom sheet menu?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212621/discussion-between-abhishek-ghaskata-and-disha-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap buttons on each page with `Hero` widget, like that:

```
Hero(
 tag: 'fab',
 child: FloatingActionButton()
);
```

Comment: I have only one floating button in main home screen and I just wanna open new screen to click on it. But there should be bottom menu visible in new screen and floating button will be set on app bar with animation like design screen.

Comment: @DishaPatel Then try to create the same bottom menu on second screen, and wrap both of bottom menus on two screens in ' Hero(tag: 'bottomMenu', child:...)'

Comment: It would not be possible because I will not manage it accordingly with tab. I want only one bottom menu in whole app. Can you please help me for this?

Comment: @DishaPatel I don't think you can do it. If you'll try the method I suggested, these two bottom menus will look to user like it's the same one, thanks to Hero animation.

Comment: Yes you are right that it will look same but how can I manage bottom menus. Suppose user is on second page when click on FAB button then he clicks on second tab and then come to back then he will show this second screen rather than first screen

Comment: @DishaPatel I carefully reviewed your example, and I think I know what exactly you need. Please see my new answer.

Answer (score 0):

With the design you want to achieve, I suggest you to use [sliding_up_panel](https://pub.dev/packages/sliding_up_panel) instead of pushing new screen.

It has a parameter `collapsed`, in which you can put `FloatingActionButton` to expand panel on tap, and show the same button inside the expanded panel. Just set panel non-draggable, and it won't expand on swipe.

Please read it's documentation carefully, I'm sure you can achieve the effect you want with this widget.

Comment: You can see that my both screens app bar is different as you suggested that I need to use sliding up panel. But with the use of it I will not get my desired output. Because sliding channel will come from bottom and I have to show bottom menu in both page.

Comment: @DishaPatel I think you can shift panel to have margin on the bottom so it won't cover bottom bar.

Comment: @DishaPatel Sliding_up_panel is just a widget, which you can, in theory, place anywhere on the screen. Just play with numbers :)

Comment: @DishaPatel As I see from in your case, you can simply wrap your page's content in `Stack`, and add `SlidingUpPanel` on top of it, maybe wrapped in `Positioned(bottom: 40, ...)`. In this case it won't cover bottom bar, and you will achieve design you want.

Comment: @DishaPatel Resumbitted my comment with fixed typos:) Did you tried my solution?

Comment: I used HERO animation to open new screen but HERO animation is not applied for pushed name or tab navigator. I find many solution for it but it didn't work.

you can check my question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61500713/flutter-hero-animation-is-not-working-with-tab-navigator